# Are ES6 arrow functions incompatible with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-injector, arrow-functions

Here's a normal ES5 function in my Angular code which works:

```
app.run(function($templateCache){ $templateCache.put('/some','thing') });
```

I wanted to convert it to ES6 arrow function

```
app.run($templateCache => $templateCache.put('/some','thing'));
```

but it gives the error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: '/some'Provider <- '/some'
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0='%2Fsome'Provider%20%3C-%20'%2Fsome'
REGEX_STRING_REGEXP  @ angular.js:68
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4287
getService           @ angular.js:4435
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4292
getService           @ angular.js:4435
invoke               @ angular.js:4467
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4297
forEach              @ angular.js:336
createInjector       @ angular.js:4297
doBootstrap          @ angular.js:1657
bootstrap            @ angular.js:1678
angularInit          @ angular.js:1572
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28821
trigger              @ angular.js:3022
eventHandler         @ angular.js:3296
```

Are ES6 arrow functions incompatible with Angular?

---

EDIT: I thought perhaps Angular isn't able to infer the name `$templateCache` and so unable to inject it but then I logged it to console and it does show it correctly:

```
app.run($templateCache=>console.log($templateCache));
// => 
//  Object {}
//      destroy: function()
//      get: function(key)
//      info: function()
//      put: function(key, value)
//      remove: function(key)
//      removeAll: function()
//      __proto__: Object
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the names of function's parameters, since it will stop working the moment you minify your code. Use something like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate).

Comment: The only difference seems to be that your function does return something. And the syntax of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct. [Your version of AngularJS is not compatible with arrow functions that make use of $injector.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.6/src/auto/injector.js#L77)

This is mainly because AngularJS 1.4.6 makes use of `(Function).toString`, which does not start with `function(` for arrow functions, at least in Firefox:

```
>var a = () => 5
function a()
>a.toString()
"() => 5"  // not "function a() {return 5;}"
```

AngularJS supports the arrow notation from [1.5.0 onwards](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/44a96a4c140873d9fd8484d870af83a0bb9acabd).

Comment: Your links show that basic support for arrow functions has existed since Angular 1.4.4. (Note the v1.4.4 tag on the commit in your second link.) I think the actual commit that bears on the OP's code is [commit 03726f7f](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/03726f7fbd5d71c0604b8dd40e97cb2fb0fb777f), which added support for arrow functions with an unparenthesized parameter for Angular 1.5.

Answer (score 3):

I tried another variation which worked: `(x)=>…` (instead of `x=>…`)

```
app.run(($templateCache) => $templateCache.put('/some','thing'));
```

I guess it needs parentheses for some reason