# Passing scope variables to an AngularJS controller using fat arrows

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, lexical-scope

I'm updating an AngularJS application to use fat arrow syntax for anonymous functions. I know that I [need to use version 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700041/are-es6-fat-arrow-functions-incompatible-with-angular#answer-32700361), but some things still don't work. For example, here I have a custom directive that passes the string 'hello' to its controller, which then outputs the string as an alert:

```
<div data-my-directive="hello">Text that will be replaced by my-template</div>

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', () => (
            {
                restrict: 'A',
                templateUrl: 'my-template',
                controller: 'myController',
                controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
                bindToController: true,
                scope: {myVariable : '@myDirective'}
            }))
    .controller('myController', () => {
        alert('the scope variable is: ' + this.myVariable );
    }
```

But this alerts 'the scope variable is: undefined'.

If I change the controller definition to use ES5 syntax, then it alerts 'the scope variable is: hello', as expected.

```
    .controller('myController', function() {
        alert('the scope variable is: ' + this.myVariable);
    }
```

I guess that this is something to do with the [binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).

Is there a way to use the fat arrow notation when passing scope variables as above?

Comment: Please,Let me know is it working or not?

Comment: @JMK The second code block (without the fat arrow) is ES5 syntax

Comment: Not fat, just arrow. And it's not a _"syntax for anonymous functions". An arrow function is a special type of function. `controller` expects a constructor function, which can never be an arrow function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have to use function instead of ()=>.

If you do :

```
.controller('myController', () => {
    console.log(this); // -> window
})
```

If you use arrow function here, this === window. A controller need a real scope to work properly. I am pretty sure you doesn't want window as common object for all controllers in your app :)

Arrow function is really useful with class and callback but should not be use every time.

Answer (score 1):

Angular calls the controller function like this: `fn.apply(self, args);` 
where `self` (which becomes `this` in the invoked function) is an object that has the required fields - i.e. `myVariable` in the example.

[Arrow functions ignore the first of `apply`'s arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Invoked_through_call_or_apply). So as @Yoann says, we must use `function() {...}` rather than `() => {...}`.