# Angular.js: 13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'enfermerosController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing, angular-controller

i'm getting `Angular.js: 13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'enfermerosController' is not a function, got undefined`error I don't know what is happening. Found in some places that it's maybe i'm calling ng-app twice or my module but I don't. I'm using `Angular 1.5.3` and it's my first time with this problem. I will be grateful with any help you can give.

Thanks

This is my router

```
'use strict'
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)  {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: '/views/admin/partials/hola.html',
          controller: 'adminController'
      })
      $routeProvider.when('/admin/geriatras', {
          templateUrl: '/views/admin/partials/geriatras.html',
          controller: 'geriatrasController'
      })
      $routeProvider.when('/admin/medicos', {
          templateUrl: '/views/admin/partials/medicos.html',
          controller: 'medicosController'
      })
      $routeProvider.when('/admin/enfermeros', {
          templateUrl: '/views/admin/partials/enfermeros.html',
          controller: 'enfermerosController'
      })
      $routeProvider.when('/admin/pacientes', {
          templateUrl: '/views/admin/partials/pacientes.html',
          controller: 'pacientesController'
      })
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        })
    }])
```

and after this is one of my controllers `pacientesController` (with all I have the same problem)

```
'use strict'
myApp.controller('pacientesController',['$scope', ($scope) =>  {
 $scope.hello = "hello"
  }])
```

This is `enfermerosController`  (as you see, there's no code yet in my controllers)

```
'use strict'
myApp.controller('enfermerosController', ['$scope', function($scope)   {
}])
```

and my html is this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Hospital</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/dist/css/Matadero.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>:D</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Hospital</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="hidden-xs">!!Nombre Usuario Loggeado¡¡</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <!-- Menu Body -->
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Perfil</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Cerrar sesión</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

      <!-- search form -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu" ng-controller="navController">
        <li class="header">Menú</li>
        <li class="active treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Personal Médico</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/admin/geriatras')}"><a href="/admin/geriatras"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Geriatras</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/admin/medicos')}"><a href="/admin/medicos"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Médicos</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/admin/enfermeros')}"><a href="/admin/enfermeros"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Enfermeros</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: isActive('/admin/pacientes')}"><a href="/admin/pacientes"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Pacientes</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Panel de Control</small>
      </h1>

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">





        <div ng-view="">

        </div>






    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Equipo Fiucsa</b>
    </div>
    <strong>Tecnológico de Monterrey &copy; 2016 <a href="http://github.com">Repositorio</a>.</strong>
  </footer>


  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->



<!--Angular -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/cuestionarioController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/geriatrasController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/medicosController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/enfermerosController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/navController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/controllers/adminController.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/public/assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post definition of enfermerosController.

Comment: I just updated with enfermerosController code :)

Comment: And in what file is `var myApp = angular.module...` defined?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: Looks good. Something else is the problem. Try to set up a demo, otherwise it's hard to guess.

Comment: I just found the error, let me post and you will see. Give me a second. And thank you for your time i'm so grateful with you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just found my error and it was the arrow functions when I define my controllers. I think we can only use arrow functions inside controllers not when you define it

theres a little explanation here:

[Are ES6 arrow functions incompatible with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700041/are-es6-fat-arrow-functions-incompatible-with-angular)